# Blank Shapefile output?

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, update, map-drawing

When executing the following command string in the active browser, Qgis projects the triangle polygon and associated attribute table correctly.

Upon reopening the shapefile in a new browser, the attribute table is lost and no polygon exists.

Is the map registry update command incorrect prior to the 'writer' command, or is the writer command itself improper?

Thanks for any clues.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *

# create layer
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsq:4326&field=BOTTOM:integer(8)&field=TOP:integer(8)&field=K:integer(10)&field=R:integer(10)&index=yes', 'poly_temp' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()

# start editing
layer.startEditing()

# add the polygon
base = QgsFeature()
fields = layer.dataProvider().fields()
base.setFields(fields)
base["BOTTOM"] = "50"
base["TOP"] = "100"
base["K"] = "0.003"
base["R"] = "0.00005"

# Draw feature 
poly1 = [QgsPoint(50,50), QgsPoint(25,30), QgsPoint(60,30)]
base.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([poly1]))
ok, of = layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([base])
iface.mapCanvas().refresh()

# update fields
layer.updateFeature(base)
layer.updateFields()

# update extent of the layer
layer.updateExtents()

# finish editing
layer.commitChanges()

# add the layer to the canvas
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])

# write layer to file
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("C:\Users\...\Base_Layer.shp", "CP1250", pr.fields(), QGis.WKBPolygon, None, "ESRI Shapefile" )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!
Passing through significant novice headache(s), the following bit of code resolved my problems and properly saved the shapefile with all the nitty bits.  Thanks to StackExchange and [Nathan's QGIS blog](http://nathanw.net/).

```
# create GIS interface reference and Base_layer with fields
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=epsq:4326&field=BOTTOM:string(8)&field=TOP:string(8)&field=K:string(10)&field=R:string(10)&index=yes', 'Base_Layer' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()

# start editing
layer.startEditing()

# create polygon reference and establish attribute values
base = QgsFeature()
fields = pr.fields()
base.setFields(fields)
base["BOTTOM"] = "50" 
base["TOP"] = "100" 
base["K"] = "0.003" 
base["R"] = "0.00002" 

# Draw feature polgon
poly1 = [QgsPoint(50,50), QgsPoint(25,30), QgsPoint(60,30)]
base.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolygon([poly1]))
pr.addFeatures([base])

# update fields, layer extents, and finalize edits
layer.updateFeature(base)
layer.updateFields()
layer.updateExtents()
layer.commitChanges()

# add the layer to the canvas and write to file
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("C:\...\Base_Layer.shp", "CP1250", fields, QGis.WKBPolygon, None, "ESRI Shapefile" )
writer.addFeature(base)
del writer
```